# Microsoft Graph api user lookup

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, microsoft-graph, column-settings

I have a user lookup field in SharePoint however the id given is the lookup id and not the userid.

Where is the lookup id referencing?

Looking at a link like this: [Create list relationships by using unique and lookup columns](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632).

It seems to suggest it is in another list however I can't find it.

Any ideas on how to find this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the lookup list, we can open the current list and go to **List Settings**->**Columns**->Find and click the lookup field, then we can find the lookup list is here.

[image]